# Does nth mean anything in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

Just a question I was wondering, does the keyword nth in CSS mean anything?

Is an acronym/abbreviation?

Comment: Context is everything. Have you seen it as part of a pseudo-class such as `:nth-child()`?

Comment: Sorry my question was maybe not clear but SLaks answered it perfectly. I am not English so I didn't know this obvious answer :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's an [ordinal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)):

1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ..., nth

Comment: nth - ADJECTIVE - Mathematics
Denoting an unspecified member of a series of numbers or enumerated items.

‘systematic sampling by taking every nth name from the list’
‘for the nth time that day they were forced to relate the whole story’

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nth

Answer (score 7):

There are the [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Pseudo-classes):

- [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child)
- [:nth-last-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-child)
- [:nth-last-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-of-type)
- [:nth-of-type()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)